# except condition in mysql query..

Tags: php, mysql

i have table with following structure,

```
name (type: TEXT)
price (type: INT)
color (type: TEXT)
vehicletype (type: TEXT) eg. SEDAN/SUV
```

now i want to retrieve (name, price, color, vehicletype) If its a black sedan, I'm ready to pay 10,000, but if its red or white, then no more than 8,000. For any other color I won't go above 7,000, except if its an SUV, in which case my budget is upto 15,000 for a black one or upto 14,000 for any other color.
i have this query, but it's not worked,

```
SELECT name, price, color, vehicletype FROM carrecords WHERE
(vehicletype = 'SEDAN' AND color  = 'black' AND price <= 10000) OR
(vehicletype = 'SEDAN' AND color IN('red','white') AND price <= 8000 ) OR
(vehicletype  = 'SEDAN' /* here I tried != "SUV" as well - no luck*/  AND color NOT IN('red','white','black') AND price <= 7000) OR
(vehicletype = 'SUV' AND color  = 'black' AND price <= 15000) OR
(vehicletype = 'SUV' AND color  != 'black' AND price <= 14000)
ORDER BY price ASC
```

so, is there any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name, price, color, vehicletype FROM carrecords WHERE
-- black sedans up to 10k
(vehicletype = 'SEDAN' AND color  = 'black' AND price <= 10000)
-- red or white sedans up to 8k
OR (vehicletype = 'SEDAN' AND color IN('red','white') AND price <= 8000 )
-- black SUV up to 15k
OR (vehicletype = 'SUV' AND color  = 'black' AND price <= 15000)
-- non-black SUV up to 14k
OR (vehicletype = 'SUV' AND color  != 'black' AND price <= 14000)
-- any other vehicle up to 7k
OR (price <= 7000)
ORDER BY price ASC
```

Comment: Nice. The `color  != 'black'` can be left out.

Comment: @ypercube Yes it can - so can the comments. I wanted the code to show my intentions, at the cost of brevity and optimization (Depending on the cars in the DB putting `price <= 7000` first could be a straightforward speedup)