# SQL using UNION operator from ELANCE

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [except condition in mysql query..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015568/except-condition-in-mysql-query)

Consider a table called carrecords with the following structure:

name (type: TEXT)
price (type: INT)
color (type: TEXT)
vehicletype (type: TEXT) eg. SEDAN/SUV

A customer wants to see the details (name, price, color, vehicletype) of the vehicles that suit his preferences. This is what he says:

"If its a black sedan, I'm ready to pay 10,000, but if its red or white, then no more than 8,000. For any other color I won't go above 7,000, except if its an SUV, in which case my budget is upto 15,000 for a black one or upto 14,000 for any other color."

Write a query that returns the desired information in ascending order of price.

My solution is as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM carrecords
WHERE name='SEDAN' 
     AND  color='black'
     AND price=10000
UNION
SELECT *
FROM carrecords
WHERE name='SEDAN'
      AND color='RED' OR color='WHITE'
      AND price<=8000
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM carrecords
WHERE name='SEDAN'
     AND color!='BLACK'
     AND price<=7000
UNION
SELECT *
FROM carrecords
WHERE name='SUV'
      AND color='BLACK'
      AND price<=15000
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM carrecords
WHERE name='SUV'
     AND color!='BLACK'
     AND price<=14000
ORDER BY price;
```

Comment: any solution is welcome guys...

Comment: This seems like a statement more than a question. Are you forced to use unions? Are you looking for some better way?

Comment: No that was my solution using UNION operator.Any other solution is good for me.

Comment: @Venk: Is this homework?

Comment: No I am going through some tutorial and went through these exercise problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think the values 'SUV' and 'SEDAN' are in the 'type' column, not in the 'name' column.  Also, you can write it more succinctly like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM carrecords
WHERE (type='SEDAN' 
     AND ((color='BLACK'
          AND price<=10000)
     OR (color IN ('RED', 'WHITE')
          AND price<=8000)
     OR (color NOT IN ('BLACK', 'RED', 'WHITE')
          AND price<=7000)))
     OR
     (type='SUV' 
     AND ((color='BLACK'
          AND price<=15000)
     OR (color != 'BLACK'
         AND price<=14000))
ORDER BY price
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could do this without the Union:

```
Select * from carrecords
where (type='Sudan' AND price <= 7000) 
OR (type='Sudan' and color in ('Red','White') and price <= 8000) 
OR (type='Sudan' AND color = 'Black' AND price <= 10000)
OR (type='SUV' and price <=14000)
OR (type='SUV' and color='Black' and price <=15000)
order by price
```

Comment: You could also optimize/simplify the AND/OR criteria using Boolean Algebra, but I purposefully kept it aligned to the statements for comparison.